# iOS store CLLocation Core data as transformable NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName error CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, cllocation

I'm trying to store CLLocation object in core data. I set core data NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName :

[image]

But when I created my NSEntityDescription to add the object:

```
Locations *location= [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Locations" inManagedObjectContext:self.cdManager.managedObjectContext];
```

I'm getting this error:

```
CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName' was found for attribute 'locations' on entity 'Locations'
```

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong or why of the error I'm getting? or how can this be fix?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you what the problem is. You configured your model to use a class named `NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName` as the value transformer, but there is no class with that name.

The string that you enter there must be a name of a subclass of `NSValueTransformer` that exists in your project. If you leave the field blank, Core Data uses `NSCoding` to encode values. Since you're wanting to encode `CLLocation`, and since `CLLocation` implements `NSCoding`, you should just leave that text field blank. Core Data will call `NSCoding` methods to convert the objects to/from `NSData`.

Answer (score -3):

`CLLocation` does not implement the `NSCoding` protocol so it cannot be transformed like this.

I would suggest storing the latitude and longitude in core data and then you can create `CLLocation` instances from the data as needed.

Comment: But according to the documentation, `CLLocation` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`, which inherits from `NSCoding`.

Comment: Ahh, missed that one in my scan :)  I would still store the raw values.